# Numerical evaluation expression not returning result in requested precision

Tags: numerics, numerical-value, precision-and-accuracy

I have a long list of descriptive statistical quantities for a univariate list of data. The problem is that the set number of significant figures is ignored by the `N[...,sigs]` for most expressions. In the code they are easily identified with a comment `(* sigs not working *)`.

Why are they not returned in requested precision of 3 significant figures? How can I fix this?

```
raw = {1.32, 1.37, 1.43, 1.32, 1.36, 1.33, 1.38, 1.35, 1.48, 1.28, 
   1.31, 1.52, 1.51, 1.33, 1.32, 1.27, 1.35, 1.40, 1.27, 1.39, 1.50, 
   1.31, 1.34, 1.48, 1.36, 1.33, 1.40, 1.29, 1.35, 1.36, 1.33, 1.30, 
   1.28, 1.32, 1.34, 1.33, 1.29, 1.34, 1.34, 1.29, 1.35, 1.52, 1.29, 
   1.38, 1.40, 1.28, 1.36, 1.36, 1.32, 1.62, 1.36, 1.34, 1.33, 1.33, 
   1.30, 1.31, 1.33, 1.32, 1.36, 1.41};
    sigs = 3;
    {"n", n = Length[raw]}
    {"range", range = N[Max[raw] - Min[raw], sigs]}
    {"midrange", 
     midrange = N[Min[raw] + range/2, sigs]}(* sigs not working *)
    {"μ ", μ = N[Mean[raw], sigs]}(* sigs not working *)
    {"median", median = N[Median[raw], sigs]}
    {"mode", mode = N[Commonest[raw][[1]], sigs]}
    {"rms", rms = N[RootMeanSquare[raw], sigs]}(* sigs not working *)
    {"σ2", σ2 = 
      N[Variance[raw], sigs]}(* sigs not working *)
    {"σ", σ = 
      N[Sqrt[σ2], sigs]}(* sigs not working *)
    {"σmean", σmean = 
      N[MeanDeviation[raw], sigs]}(* sigs not working *)
    {"Cvar", Cvar = N[σ/μ, sigs]}(* sigs not working *)
    {"Es", Es = 
      N[(6745/10000) StandardDeviation[raw], 
       sigsup]}(* sigs not working *)
    {"Em", Em = N[Es/Sqrt[n], sigsup]}(* sigs not working *)
    {"skew", skew = N[Skewness[raw], sigsdn]}(* sigs not working *)
    {"kurt", kurt = N[Kurtosis[raw], sigsdn]}(* sigs not working *)
```

Comment: Don’t use the machine-precision number `.6745`. That will force the conversion of your result to `MachinePrecision`. You could use `6745/10000`, ``.6745`3``, or `SetPrecision[.6745, sigs]` instead.

Comment: You can try `Es = N[Rationalize[.6745] σ, sigs]` and wrap `Rationalize` around most other constants which include a decimal point that you put in your code. The rules are a little more complicated than that, but this should be a simple rule to get you most of the way there

Comment: @MarcoB thank you it worked. but now i have another problem. for some odd reason all the other expressions that worked before are no longer setting precision. would you mind looking at it for me?  the expressions that aren't working are commented

Comment: @Bill Thank you for your suggestion but MarcoB  suggested something that worked. However since fixing those two expressions for some odd reason the other expressions no longer working for precision. Would you mind having a look at it?

Comment: Your edit appeared to have removed the assignment to `raw` which I think might have been something like `raw={1,2,3,4,5}` If I insert that near the top most of it starts working again. But it starts failing at cvar which I assume is another mixup. Does this give you enough to start tracking that down?

Comment: @Bill oops my bad. the `raw={}1,2,3,4,5}` was just a short test case.which by the way works. the set of data i need to work with is: 

`raw = {1.32, 1.37, 1.43,...}`  was added to the code above.

but the precision doesn't seem to be working on this set of data. One more look please.

Comment: If I change `raw={1.32,..}` to `raw=Rationalize[{1.32,..}]` then everything down to `cvar` starts working. And the reason it fails there is that if you copy and paste exactly your code above into a new fresh notebook and you look closely you should see that `sigsup` and `sigsdn` are blue, not black, which is supposed to let you notice that you haven't assigned values to either of those. If I change `sigs=3;` to `sigs=3;sigsup=3;sigsdn=3;` and run your code then everything appears to work now. Please verify that.

Comment: @Bill thank you so much. it worked. i had been struggling with this a good part of the day.